# Recharts not working in React - 'recharts' does not contain an export named 'Recharts'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I want to draw the graph using Recharts.

I am currently looking at the example given in the documentation on their website.

Once I copy their code into my application I encounter the following error:

```
'recharts' does not contain an export named 'Recharts'.
```

Could something in packet packs go wrong?

And how can I clear this error?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import Api from '../../Api'
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { Recharts } from 'recharts';

const { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } = Recharts;
    const data = [
      { name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400 },
      { name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210 },
      { name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290 },
      { name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000 },
      { name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181 },
      { name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500 },
      { name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100 },
    ];

 render() {

   return (
      <div className="container">
         <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={this.data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis yAxisId="left" />
       <YAxis yAxisId="right" orientation="right" />
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line yAxisId="left" type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Line yAxisId="right" type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart> 

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are importing it wrong. You can either import it like this:

```
import * as Recharts from 'recharts';
```

or you can import the individual exports directly like this:

```
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from 'recharts';
```